# Creating a 20 count range from a string of numbers

Tags: sql-server, range

I have a table (l.FICO) that returns a string of numbers (xxx) ranging from 500 - 800. What I am trying occomplish, is that I'd like the (XXX) to return in a particular range. IE. 500-519, 520-539, 540-559, 560-579, etc.

So for instance a "FICO" returns with the result of 607, the range that i would like that captured in is 600-619. If a FICO returns as 622, then it would need to be capture in the range of 620-639. If a FICO is returned as 652 then it would need to be caputred in 640-659, etc.

I'm trying to avoid having to create an additional table and would like to just plug this into my SELECT portion of my query using MsSQL Server

Comment: I think you should show an example of your data, the desired output and a query you have tried.  It's not clear what you're trying to do.  My gut instinct is you want to use modulo arithmetic to isolate the ranges, but it's pretty hard to know exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you want a count of records within the defined ranges?  If so, case statements can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your table.

```
    select 
    Member_PK
    ,case  when Member_PK between 1 and 10 then '1 to 10'
    when Member_PK between 11 and 20 then '11 to 20'
    when Member_PK between 21 and 300 then '21 to 300'
    when Member_PK between 301 and 500 then '301 to 500'
    else 'over 500'
    end as Range

    from
    member
```

Comment: Though a good suggestion, unfortunately I dont want to input a "Case" statement over and over as outlined in your suggestion. I'm looking for a shorter statement.